# Speaking between two Sidrahs when reading a double Sidrah

Tags: halacha, minhag, hefsek-interruption, shnayim-mikra

While saying [*Shnayim Mikrah V'echad Targum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shnayim_mikra_ve-echad_targum), it is best not to talk. Magen Avraham ([285:11](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1491)) writes:

> וְטוֹב שֶׁלֹּא יַפְסִיק כְּלַל בְּשִׂיחָה
>
> It is good to not interrupt at all by speaking.

*Ba'er Heiteiv* (285:1) goes even further:

> ואיסור גדול להפסיק בקריאת שמו״ת בדיבור
>
> And it is a great prohibition to interrupt while reading *Shnayim Mikrah V'echad Targum* with speech.

What about a week when we read a [double *Sidrah*](http://www.aish.com/atr/Double_Torah_Portion.html)? May one speak between the two *Sidrahs*?

Comment: One may talk in between Parshios in the Torah. A Parsha ends after a "Fay" or "Samach". I believe all Sidrahs except for Vayigash end with either one of those.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that when two *Sidrahs* are read together, they become - for now - a single *Sidrah*. Consider that the last *possuk* of the weekly portion is repeated so as to end with *mikra*. In double *Sidrah* weeks, this only applies to the final verse of the second *Sidrah*.

Most of the double *Sidrahs* are short enough that even together, they're not that long. (*Matos-Mas'ei* being the exception.) If you do need to pause in the middle, you can do so at any *parsha* break (a *Pei* or *Samech*).

Comment: Please can you add some sources?

Comment: I have none accessible at the moment. I have a vague memory of the Shlah, _Maseches Shabbos_, speaking of this. Will update with sources when I have a chance.